# Simultaneous Validation of Multiple Model Updates in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

In rails you can use accepts_nested_attributes_for to create multiple models simultaneously in a parent child relationship.  However suppose you have that same relationship, but you want to update a field on both models simultaneously, where if one model fails validation, you can be sure that the other model will not save as well.  How could this be done?

```
def edit_multiple
  @first=First.update(first_params)
  @second=Second.update(second_params)
end
```

If @first passes validations but @second does not, then we will have a situation that I don't want: one model is updating but the other is not.

Comment: Is this always going to be the case? If so you can set `autosave: true` on the relationship between the two objects. http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/AutosaveAssociation.html -- if this seems like the right approach for you I can add more of an answer based on this if you'd like.

Comment: Unfortunately it is specific to one acition that I want this to happen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That was transactions are for:

```
First.transaction do
  @first=First.update(first_params)
  @second=Second.update(second_params)
end
```

Now both of them succeed or fail together. More info at [ActiveRecord transactions](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Transactions/ClassMethods.html)

Comment: Sure they will, but it will end with an exception in best case and half saved objects in worst case (no bang! on that method call), it will not end with objects with non-empty error hash that you can render to the user.

Answer (score 0):

First check if all model instances are `@model.valid?` then do a save without validation `@model.save(validate: false)`

Putting a `transaction` as boulder suggested is still a good idea in case an unexpected exception occurs